# ajax live update text in div element

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I'¨m trying to update the content of a DIV element with ajax. I got it working with an INPUT field, but the DIV element does not change values.

Here is my html:

```
    <form>
    <select name="hdd" id="hdd" class="select-field">
        <option value="C" default="default">C</option>
        <option value="A">A</option>
        <option value="B">B</option>
        <option value="C">C</option>
        <option value="D">D</option>
    </select>
</form>

    <div id="files">test</div>
```

And here is my ajax:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var $files = $(this).attr("div#files");

    $("#hdd").keyup(function () {
        $files.val(this.value);
    });

    $("#hdd").blur(function () {
        $files.val(this.value);
    });

});
```

I think the issue is with this line: `var $files = $(this).attr("div#files");` ?

[JSFiddle link to my test script](http://jsfiddle.net/K9cmy/290/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming, what you're trying to target here is the `#files` object in your DOM, you can change this:

```
var $files = $(this).attr("div#files");
```

to this:

```
var $files = $("#files");
```

and, a `div` does not have a `.val()` method.  Use `.html()` instead like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    $("#hdd").on("keyup blur change", function () {
        $("#files").html(this.value);
    });

});
```

Note: how with `.on()` you can specify multiple events at once that will all call the same event handler, thus removing the need to copy your code.

---

Or, perhaps all you need is the `"change"` event which fires whenever the user commits a new value for the `<select>` control:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    $("#hdd").on("change", function () {
        $("#files").html(this.value);
    });

});
```

Comment: The last code you provided worked, given that I changed $("#files").val(this.value) to $("#files").html(this.value). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When updating DIVs, use `html("contents")` in stead of `val("contents")`. The same goes for other elements like SPAN, TD, etc.

Example:

```
$("#hdd").blur(function () {
    $files.html(this.value);
});
```